# How to enable Intellisense for Taghelpers on Views in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, intellisense, tag-helpers

I am trying to develop an **Asp .Net Core MVC** app on my **Mac** using **Visual Studio Code**. 
Things mostly work ok, except I can't make **Intellisense** to work for **Taghelpers** in my Views. 
I have seen others posting the same issue for Visual Studio but not for Visual Studio Code on a Mac. I am not sure how much does this make a difference though. I am new to Asp in general.

I have

```
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
```

and

```
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
```

on project.json.

And I also have

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

on the _ViewImports.cshtml

Except for Taghelpers, Intellisense works fine on Views.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly TagHelper IntelliSense is not currently supported in Visual Studio Code. It is something we're working on for the future though!